# Material-UI IE11 Multiple Accordions - last chosen accordion won't close if I select a new one

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, internet-explorer-11, accordion

I have implemented several expandable menus using MUI Accordion's. Their expansion is controlled through the "expanded" property. MUI release is 4.10.2.

In recent browsers each Accordion closes when I open one of the others. I have implemented this behavior  through ClickAwayListener's that wrap the content of the AccordionDetails.

In IE11 this does not happen entirely. What I see is that the ClickAwayListener does not catch the mouse click on the sibling AccordionSummary's. Mouseclicks in all other parts of the page are caught correctly.

[image: multiple MUI-accordions remain open in IE11]

In all recent browsers the click on the sibling AccordionSummary is correctly used to open it, and then it arrives to the ClickAwayListener of the previously chosen menu (and closes it). In IE11 this does not happen.

I am not using preventDefault in any part of the page. No error message is reported to the IE11 console.

I have created a codesandbox that contains the minimal code that fails on my website:

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-galileo-gqxz9

Unfortunately this codesandbox page does not run in IE11, so the issue is not really reproducible.

Comment: MSIE has < 3% market share in all of the USA. What percentage of your users are using MSIE 11? This might not be anything you need to worry about. If you're not in the US, check this for stats in your area. https://gs.statcounter.com/browser-market-share/desktop/united-states-of-america

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno - I couldn't imagine a single comment more irrelevant than yours.

Comment: I suggest you try to open the console while testing the issue in the IE 11 browser to see whether it is showing any error messages. It can give some hints about the issue. If possible please try to share the sample code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - I already wrote there is no message on the console.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - I see you have some track record on IE11. I assume there's something that inhibits event bubbling in AccordionSummary's, can you name some situations where that could occur? If I google around I see that there are cases in which IE11 does not respect the preventDefault contract, but it's not the case here.

Comment: You said," I have implemented this behavior through ClickAwayListener's that wrap the content of the AccordionDetails." Can you please show a code example? We can try to make a test with it to check for the issue. It can help us properly understand the issue. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT - I have prepared a codesandbox page with the minimal sample code. URL is now inside the question text. Hope it will give you some clue.

Comment: I can reproduce the said issue with the IE 11 browser, but I did not get any way to fix this issue from the IE side. I suggest you provide the feedback to Material UI developers on their [Github page](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues). Thanks for your understanding.